# Bash script to merge two lines of output into one

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following bash script on windows to generate MD5 hashes for a list of files in a folder:

`$ ls -rt | while read -r file; do (()); CertUtil -hashfile "${file}" MD5 >> foo.txt; done;`

For each file `bar`, I get the following two lines:

```
MD5 hash of file bar:
0ae58a1af151446ac8b283b6e70ea157
```

I would like to pipe the output to reformat as:

```
0ae58a1af151446ac8b283b6e70ea157   bar
```

I suppose this can be done with `sed` ? Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$ ls -rt | while read -r file; do echo $(CertUtil -hashfile "${file}" MD5) "${file}" >> foo.txt; done;
```

But even better would be ([safer](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) to use filename expansion than to iterate over `ls` output):

```
for file in *; do
    echo "$(CertUtil -hashfile "${file}" MD5)   ${file}" >> foo.txt
done
```

I'm not sure for `CertUtil`, but if you can install GNU `md5sum`, the complete script can be replaced with:

```
md5sum * >>foo.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a bit better, but I now get an extra piece of text `CertUtil -hash command completed sucessfully`  So, is there a way of filtering out this line ?

Comment: Yes! md5sum is much better. Except, there is an asterisk at the front of each file name

Comment: I'm not familiar with `CertUtil`, but you should check if it has some option to silence the verbose/debug output.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use `md5sum` instead.

Comment: re: md5sum, I'm not seeing any asterisk in front.. But you can strip it simply with `sed s/^\*//` filter.

Comment: Thanks. This filter didn't work on windows git bash. I will just live with the asterisk, I guess.

Comment: OK, this works:  `md5sum * | sed s/\*//  >> foo.txt`

Comment: The asterisk indicates that md5sum is reading in binary mode ( a windows thing, since there is also text mode)